# How to calculate the average as per group in MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

As per below table how to calculate the average calls made by visitor per region in MS Excel.

[image]

Comment: Try a Pivot Table

Comment: Could you please please provide any example for reference.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of using pivot tables in this forum and elsewhere.  Do some research and edit your question to show what you have tried.

Comment: Thank You @Ron. I am able to achieve using Pivot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Pivot table.

A PivotTable is an interactive way to quickly summarize large amounts of data. You can use a PivotTable to analyze numerical data in detail, and answer unanticipated questions about your data. A PivotTable is especially designed for: Querying large amounts of data in many user-friendly ways.

If you want to know morea about pivot tables please follow this [Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-pivottables-and-pivotcharts-527c8fa3-02c0-445a-a2db-7794676bce96)

If you want to learn how to use pivot tables please follow this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

i hope this information can be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the newest version and want to stick with formulas:

```
=LET(x, UNIQUE(region_range),
y, AVERAGEIF(region_range, x, call_range),
IF(SEQUENCE(1,2)=1,x,y))
```

For example:
[image]

But pivot tables as recommended by @Ron Rosenfeld are likely faster. It would be a good idea to become familiar with them for possible future use in my opinion, as they can be handy for a variety of different situations.